# Load once core for AJAX Applications (PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm building a gallery website fully functional with AJAX (jquery) Via PHP.

I have a CORE ready from other website i've built.

My problem is this: I want to load website core (db, urlmanager, defines&constants etc) only once and not on every page I load with ajax.

I.E: i have this pages: gallery.php, init.php, albums.php

But then when i call each one on AJAX ($.ajax...... albums.php) I need to do the "require_once ... core.php"

and also open another DB connection on each call.

Is there a solution? And if there isn't, whats the best way to fit php in ajax applications?

Comment: Simply don't include what you don't need, i.e. lazy loading.

Comment: If you don't need to support IE7 you can use local/sessionStorage to check whether if it's the first load or not.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a scripted language, so yes you do need to include (or require) all the relevant files on every page load. There are some solutions to make things easier for you, but they don't change the underlying fact.

Possible solutions:

- **Save your core files into a single `.phar` (PHP archive) file.** PHAR is a method of combining an entire library into a single file so that it is easier to load. You still need to include the phar file in your program, but once you've done that all the classes within it should be available without further includes. Further info here: http://phpmaster.com/packaging-your-apps-with-phar/
- **Use an Autoloader mechanism.** PHP has an autoload system that allows it to load classes automatically when they are referenced. This can save you from having to manually include the files you need. You still need to write an autoloader function, which does include the files it finds, and structure your code so that the autoloader can find the files, but your main codebase should then be kept free of too many includes. Read more about it here: http://phpmaster.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/
- **Use an Opcode Cache such as APC or Opcode.** These tools are PHP extensions (although the Opcode extension will be built-in when PHP 5.5 is released), that keep the PHP code in memory after it has been run through the PHP interpreter. This means that the next time you load the same code, it will run quicker as it doesn't need to be processed again. This doesn't affect the number of includes/requires in your code, but does mean that the PHP interpreter doesn't have to process them repeatedly. Here's a link for you on Opcode: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/using_php_5_5_s
- **Use a PHP compiler such as HipHop.** This is the extreme end -- just compile your entire codebase into an executable. PHP won't need to include anything ever again. You may need to restructure your codebase to make this feasible. Read about HipHop here: http://www.hiphop-php.com/wp/

Most of the above options can be combined, so for examplem, you can write a phar library that is used by an autoloader, and have an opcode cache in use to speed it up, all at the same time.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do db requests in the ajax loaded page, there's no way around it, you still need to require your db php file, since it's a brand new request.

If you don't need to do db requests, simply don't load the db file.